# What does it mean to "run" a function in Alloy?

Tags: alloy

My understanding is that functions in Alloy return a value. However, I noticed that you can run a function using a `run` command the same way you would `run` a predicate. What does running a function mean and how is this functionality used in Alloy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this respect, you can think of a function as being just like a predicate: it's a constraint, and when you run it, Alloy finds an instance that makes the constraint true. In this case, it will be a collection of arguments for the function, the values of signatures and fields, and the function result.

Running a function is used, like running a predicate, to give you a better understanding by showing you sample executions. Think of it as like running test cases, but without having to write the tests :-)